# Keyboard teleoperation for the SimulatingOneRobot tutorial on ROS Hydro

Tags: catkin, tutorial, ros-hydro, stacks, keyboard-teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to know which package I can use to teleoperate with a keyboard the stageros? because in the tutorial

http://wiki.ros.org/stage/Tutorials/SimulatingOneRobot

they told you to use teleop_base which is depracted and it is for the stacks

http://answers.ros.org/question/9207/teleop_base-deprecated-need-generic-teleop-package/#

and the other versions around are for the stacks and not for catkin

http://answers.ros.org/question/54078/stage-simulatingonerobot-tutorial-is-there-still-a-teleop_base-package/

I also wonder if the packages that are based on the stacks can be used with catkin? and I can do the following:

http://answers.ros.org/question/115261/how-to-install-an-individual-package-in-ros-hydro/

Best,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206158/keyboard-teleoperation-for-the-simulatingonerobot-tutorial-on-ros-hydro/) by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 188 on 2015-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use [teleop_twist_keyboard](http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_keyboard) on Hydro.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-03-28**:
I've also opened a ticket indicating that the tutorial you're using needs to be updated: https://github.com/rtv/Stage/issues/50